# implementation advice for how to toggle css properties of a parent div using its child checkbox in svelte

Tags: html, css, typescript, svelte

This took me way to long and I still think my implementation is rather bad and confusing, right now I'm just largely confused why things break if I remove `checkedActivities.has(activity) ? "checked" : "unchecked"` because I thought my typescript replaces this functionality. Any advice would be greatly appreceated.

```html
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    import userActivities from "../userActivities.json";
    const activityArray: string[] = userActivities.activities.map(
        ([name, icon]) => name
    );
    export let selectedActivities: String[] = activityArray.slice(0, 3);

    let checkedActivities = new Set(activityArray.slice(0, 3));
    function toggleActivitySelection(activity: string) {
        let div = document.getElementById(activity);
        if (checkedActivities.has(activity)) {
            checkedActivities.delete(activity);
            div?.classList.remove("checked");
            div?.classList.add("unchecked");
        } else {
            checkedActivities.add(activity);
            div?.classList.remove("unchecked");
            div?.classList.add("checked");
        }
        console.log(checkedActivities);
    }
</script>

<div>
    <div class="heading-bar">
        <span>Saved activities</span>
        <form action="/activities">
            <button on:click={() => console.log(selectedActivities)}
                >Done</button
            >
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-container">
        {#each activityArray as activity}
            <div
                class={checkedActivities.has(activity) ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                id={activity}
            >
                <label>
                    <input
                        class="input_checkbox"
                        id="input_checkbox"
                        type="checkbox"
                        bind:group={selectedActivities}
                        value={activity}
                        on:change={() => {
                            toggleActivitySelection(activity);
                        }}
                    />
                    {activity}
                </label>
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
    }

    label {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    div.checked:hover, div.unchecked:hover {
        border-left: 2px solid var(--color-text) !important;
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
        border-right: 2px solid var(--color-text) !important;
        border-top: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
    } 

    div.checked {
        padding-top: 0.5em;
        padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin: 0.5em 0;
        border-left: 2px solid var(--color-text) !important;
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
        border-right: 2px solid var(--color-text) !important;
        border-top: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
    }

    div.unchecked {
        padding-top: 0.5em;
        padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin: 0.5em 0;
        border-left: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
        border-right: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
        border-top: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
    }

    .heading-bar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: baseline;
        margin-top: 1.8em;
        margin-bottom: 0.6em;
    }

    .bg-container {
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: var(--color-objects);
        padding: 1em 1.4em;
    }

    #item {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    button {
        background-color: var(--color-objects);
        border: none;
        color: var(--color-text);
        font-size: 1em;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not query the DOM or modify it directly like that. All the code adding/removing classes manually should be removed.

The main issue is that `checkedActivities` is mutated without assignment, which does not trigger updates of anything that depends on it.

The toggle function should be reduceable to:

```js
function toggleActivitySelection(activity: string) {
    checkedActivities.has(activity) ?
        checkedActivities.delete(activity) :
        checkedActivities.add(activity);

   checkedActivities = checkedActivities; // triggers updates
}
```

Any class changes should happen in markup using the `class` attribute or a [`class:...` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name).

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to make your example working [ts-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-99cvbo?file=src/App.svelte)

```html
<script lang="ts">
    const userActivities = {activities:[
      {name:"name1",icon:"icon",checked:false},  
      {name:"name2",icon:"icon",checked:false},
      {name:"name3",icon:"icon",checked:false} 
    ]}
  let selectedActivities:any
</script>

<div>
    <div class="heading-bar">
        <span>Saved activities</span>
        <form action="/activities">
            <button on:click={() => console.log(selectedActivities)}
                >Done</button
            >
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-container">
        {#each  userActivities.activities as i}
            <div
                class={i.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked"}>
                <label> {i.name} 
                  <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={i.checked} on:change={_ = >selectedActivities = i} />
                </label>
               
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /* display: none; */
    }

    label {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    div.checked:hover, div.unchecked:hover {
        border-left: 2px solid var(--color-text) !important;
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
        border-right: 2px solid var(--color-text) !important;
        border-top: 2px solid var(--color-objects) !important;
    } 

    div.checked {
      color: green;
    
    }

    div.unchecked {
     color:red;
    }

   


</style>
```